# How to find a perfect match between two lists?

Tags: python

I have a list of guest name called 'namelist'.
And, I have a string which has converted into list 'sentence'.
So, how do I check whether the 'sentence' has one of the guests' name in 'namelist'?

```
import re
namelist = ['Nana','Bebe','Kuku','Bumbum']
textinSTR = ('I have invited Kuku, let him in')
sentence = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", textinSTR).split()
# I tried this
if namelist in sentence :
    print('bingo')
else :
    print('no bingo')
#kuku is in the namelist, but no bingo :(
```

Comment: Your whole list is _never_ in your string. You need to check if `any(thing in sentence for thing in namelist)`

Answer (score 0):

Python provides membership check. So you can loop over items in the `nameList` and check if that item exists in `sentence`. This membership check allows you to find a perfect match. Also, what if names start with lowercase, you should perform a case insensitive check. Using `lower()` you can lowercase the strings in the list and the sentence.

```
namelist = ['Nana','Bebe','Kuku','Bumbum', 'sarah']
sentence = ('I have invited Kuku and Sarah, let him in')

for i in namelist:
    if i.lower() in sentence.lower():
        print('Bingo! Found {} in sentence'.format(i))
    else :
        print('no bingo')


#Output:
no bingo
no bingo
Bingo! Found Kuku in sentence
no bingo
Bingo! Found sarah in sentence
```

Comment: If I want to convert their name into their nickname. Should I create another list? And how to convert?

Comment: That's a separate question. You can shorten the names in the list, removing the last two letters from each element in the list. But that could give you meaningless nicknames. For eg. Sean shortened as Sea seems meaningless and Robert nicknamed as Bob, cannot be achieved by shortening the name. In this case, you should have a new list of nicknames. If you want to also know the nickname for every name and easily access them, use a dictionary of key/value pairs. Eg. `{"Robert":"Bob"}`. If the answer was helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it.